# Synchronously inject current user after login

Tags: ember.js, initializer, ember-simple-auth

In my EmberJS application, I have a current user initializer, which injects the user into all controllers, routes, and views. It works great when logged in. I need the synchronous loading of the current user object so I can check some user permissions right off the bat.

Here's my initializer:

```
App.CurrentUserInitializer - Ember.Initializer.extent({

    name: 'current-user',
    after: 'authentication',

    initialize: function(container, app) {

      var store = container.lookup('store:main');

      app.deferReadiness();

      store.find('user', 'me').then(function (user) {

        app.register('session:user', user, {instantiate: false});

        _.forEach(['route', 'controller', 'view'], function (place) {
          app.inject(place, 'currentUser', 'session:user');
        });

        app.advanceReadiness();

      }).catch(function () {
        app.advanceReadiness();
      });
    }
});
```

Where this breaks down for me, is during login. When the app boots, the initializer is run, but the `/users/me` route returns a 401 error. If I don't catch the error and advanceReadiness, booting halts. By catching the error, the app boots, but the initializer isn't run again after login, so the current user isn't loaded.

What are my options here? I can't use @marcoow's recommended method of adding a computed property to the Session, as I need the user loaded at boot time.

I've tried forcing loading the user object on the IndexRoute as a hack, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd register a `session:current` object with `user` property being null. That would be injected into `controllers` and `routes` (not sure injecting inside views is a good idea).

So at boot time the `user` is unknown, but the user lookup is done before the router goes deeper than `application` route, the root:

In the `beforeModel` hook of the `application` route, you'll load that current user. Then:

- either you got the user and you set it `this.set('session.user', model)`
- or you'll go in the `error` hook of the `application` route, in which case you'd have to check why, and if `401` then you can redirect the user to the login route `this.transitionTo('login')`

Don't forget to set a flag on `session` if you got the `401` so that `transitionTo` will make our user lookup of `beforeModel` to not happen again until we reach the `login` route

The code to be used to load the session user and initialise it could be placed in that `session:current` object so that you could call it from the `application` route or the `login` controller.

This is for example my `session` initialiser (not exactly as I explained, but loading in the initialiser, so closer to what you hve). I used a `session` model so that I do `/session/current` and then got a user into it (or not) which has the correct id and not `me` which then would make the store to load the same user with another id, and so have twice the same user as 2 different records:

**app/models/session.js**:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import Ember from 'ember';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  user:            DS.belongsTo('user'),
  isAuthenticated: Ember.computed.bool('user.isClaimed')
});
```

**app/initializers/session.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default {
  name:  'session',
  after: 'store',

  initialize: function (container, app) {
    var store = container.lookup('store:main'),
        sid = Ember.$.cookie('sid');
    // used to register a session
    var register = function (session) {
      app.register('session:main', session, {instantiate: false});
      app.inject('route', 'session', 'session:main');
      app.inject('controller', 'session', 'session:main');
    };
    // used to create a new session and trigger the backend to get details about it
    // useful if the server is able to give an existing session while the browser doesn't know about it
    // with external providers for example
    var newSession = function () {
      var session = store.createRecord('session');
      // be sure to wipe out any invalid session ID
      Ember.$.removeCookie('sid');
      register(session);
      return session.save().then(function (model) {
        // if we got a valid new session, save its ID
        Ember.$.cookie('sid', model.get('id'));
      }).catch(function () {
        Ember.debug('error saving new session: ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ', '));
      });
    };
    // overall logic ==================
    app.deferReadiness();
    if (sid) {
      // try to load the existing session
      store.find('session', sid).then(function (model) {
        register(model);
        app.advanceReadiness();
      }).catch(function () {
        // there was a cookie for the session but it might have expired or the server invalidated it
        Ember.debug('error loading session: ' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ', '));
        newSession().finally(function () {
          app.advanceReadiness();
        });
      });
    }
    else {
      // we don't have any trace of a session, let's just create a new one
      newSession().finally(function () {
        app.advanceReadiness();
      });
    }
  }
};
```

**app/router.js**:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend();

Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('session', {path: '/'}, function(){
    this.route('login');
    this.route('logout');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

**app/templates/application.hbs** (as an example):

```
<h2 id='title'>Welcome to my app</h2>
{{#if session.isAuthenticated}}
  <a {{action 'session.logout'}}>Logout</a>
{{else}}
  {{#link-to 'session.login'}}Login{{/link-to}}
{{/if}}
{{outlet}}
```

Then once in login controller, when the user actually logs in, the server will return the `session` model with the user linked into it, so the Ember binding magic will just update the session object.

Comment: .@Huafu do you have a code example you could show? FYI - I'm using ember-simple-auth and whenever I use beforeModel on the application route, booting is halted, even when a fulfilled promise is returned.

Comment: Ah, if you are using `ember-simple-auth` then you should tell it in your question, because I'm unsure of how it works but it for sure might invalidate some part of my answer.
I'll add an example, but it'd be just without simple-auth. I heard about simple auth but didn't used it so can't really give an example of it. And YES, the goal of putting a promise in the `beforeModel` hook is to pause the router, maybe it's simple auth that halts the booting somehow but normally once the promise is fulfilled it should continue to boot

Comment: @ToddSmithSalter, just updated now with something using initialiser ;-)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the example. Sorry, I had tagged the question with ember-simple-auth. I'll be more explicit next time.

Comment: Oh, my fault! didn't pay attention to the tag!

Comment: BTW, I used `<a {{action 'session.logout'}}>Logout</a>` instead of a `link-to` so that it'll be easy to make it an `actions` in the `application` controller and cancel it. You can do the sam with the login actually, if you want a popup login instead for example